How do I reduce the height of custom scroll bar?

I have a custom scroll bar on a card element but I need the scroll bar to be smaller than the height of the element. I need it so the scroll bar can sit below the plus icon which has been put there via position absolute and positions by pixels.
The image shows what I have at the moment.
The below is code for the custom scroll bar.
I have tried adjusting the heights of each element on here and there were no changes.
Does anyone have any ideas to reduce the height of the entire scrollbar? Thank you


.image-grid-description {
  height: 420px!important;
  width: 85%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-right: 33px;
  /* Add space for custom scrollbar */
  box-sizing: content-box;
  /* Exclude padding from width */
}


/* Custom scrollbar styles */

.image-grid-description::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  /* Width of the scrollbar */
}

.image-grid-description::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /* Background of the track */
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* Set a border radius */
}

.image-grid-description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #fff;
  /* Color of the thumb */
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Rounded corners for the thumb */
  max-height: 80px;
  /* Set a specific height for the scrollbar thumb */
  min-height: 40px;
  /* Set a minimum height for usability */
  margin: 10px 0;
  /* Center the thumb within the track */
}

.image-grid-description::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555;
  /* Color of the thumb on hover */
}
<div class="grid-description" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(241, 94, 62, 0), rgba(241, 94, 62, 0)), url('<?php echo $image['url'] ?>');">
  <div class="image-grid-description">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis fringilla sapien at fermentum. Vivamus sed ultricies ex. Vivamus vehicula lobortis risus a consectetur. Aenean egestas sagittis ultrices. Nullam eget urna massa. Curabitur ultricies
      lacinia tellus, ac rutrum erat posuere et. Nullam placerat pretium purus at feugiat. Aenean scelerisque dui neque, non sodales mauris fermentum sit amet. Ut scelerisque velit nec lectus vulputate, vitae volutpat ipsum consectetur. Sed dignissim,
      orci sit amet feugiat imperdiet, elit risus vehicula lectus, quis sagittis justo elit id sem. Aliquam maximus sapien quis ex placerat sodales. Nulla vitae pretium dui, et mattis nunc. Vestibulum varius iaculis maximus. Cras id ultricies sapien,
      at accumsan nisi. Etiam ultrices, arcu nec sodales gravida, enim mi molestie erat, a faucibus nibh mi non ligula. Praesent lacinia fringilla lectus, et porta neque aliquam sed. Etiam aliquam ex et elementum dictum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-grid-description-cross">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="31.426" height="31.426" viewBox="0 0 31.426 31.426">
      <g id="Group_108" data-name="Group 108" transform="translate(-723.949 -2883.994)">
        <path id="Path_149" data-name="Path 149" d="M-18208.338,129.736v25.426" transform="translate(18948 2757.258)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="6"/>
        <path id="Path_150" data-name="Path 150" d="M0,0V25.426" transform="translate(752.375 2899.707) rotate(90)" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-width="6"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>




Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue when asking this kind of question, not just a snippet of CSS that lacks context.

I made you a snippet. Please [edit], scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and make it a [mcve] as suggested in the comment above
